# Ubuntu 18.04.3: Windows Domain Join Guide

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, windows, netplan, sssd

Good day.  Over the last few days I have gone through every guide I could find for joining Ubuntu 18.04 to a windows domain.  I have what I think is a working guide after much trial and error.  Would appreciate if others could verify.  So far I have had 100% success and a colleague has also had success.

Potential improvements may involve home directory settings.

> apt -y install realmd sssd sssd-tools libnss-sss libpam-sss adcli
>   samba-common-bin oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir packagekit
>
> vim /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

#Indentation is IMPORTANT

> ## Static IP
>
> ```
> network:
>     version: 2
>     renderer: networkd
>     ethernets:
>             eth0: #Change this to the active adapter
>                     addresses: [192.168.1.1/24] # Static IP and cidr for THIS server
>                     gateway4: 192.168.1.1 # Gateway
>                     nameservers:
>                             search: [contoso.com, contoso]
>                             addresses: [192.168.1.2]  # DNS IP
> ```
>
> ## DHCP
>
> ```
> network:
>     version: 2
>     renderer: networkd
>     ethernets:
>             eth0: #Change this to the active adapter
>                     dhcp4: true
> ```
>
> netplan apply
>    netplan try
>    realm discover contoso.com
>    realm join -U %AD Admin Account% CONTOSO.COM

#More specific join command

> realm join -U %AD Admin Account% --computer-ou %OU Path%

Move object to correct OU if not using specified method.  If object already exists it will not work.  For my large AD environment it took a while for it to show in my DC since I did not specify the DC.

> vim /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

use_fully_qualified_names = False  #Change  True to False if you want.

> systemctl restart sssd
>
> su - admin

#Example  -  If your AD name and local Sudo account are the same a conflict can occur.  You will need to do:

> su - domain//%username%
>
> id admin

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_18.04&p=realmd

Netplan: https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] to see how this site works. You are encouraged to ask a question and answer it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i this is the right place to share my experience. I have resolved a very long lasting problem, and wanted to post about it. Ubuntu 18.04 sssd ad integration works fine but a couple of hours later, ad users cannot login anymore, doing nothing some time later they can login.

I have been crazy for the last 6 months to figure out why their login are rejected. The error was "Realm not local to KDC". But i'm 100% sure it is local to KDC. I haven't find a clue until I turned on sssd debug 9.

In a multi domain environment sssd-ad auto discovery returns domain controllers (kdc) other than the dc's of ad_domain which is set in sssd.conf Of course the realm of the login is not local for the other domains.

Shortly if you are experiencing this specific problem, set ad_server = dc.yourdomain.com in sssd.conf. Don't trust sssd auto discovery in multi domain environment.